# Customize page header for even and odd pages WITHOUT fancyhdr

Tags: xetex, header-footer, koma-script, thesis, scrlayer-scrpage

I am using [MastersDoctoralThesis](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) for writing my thesis. Its default settings are:

- On even numbered pages: outer header has page number while inner header has chapter number
- On odd numbered pages: outer header has page number while inner header had section number

My university requirements are:

- On even numbered pages: outer header should have section number while inner header should have thesis title
- On odd numbered pages: outer header should have university name while inner header should have chapter number

I am successful in putting university name on page headers. However, I am unable to make the desired layout. I have done some work on lines 277-295 of `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls`. I have commented some original code.

```
\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\providepairofpagestyles{thesisSimple}{%
    \clearpairofpagestyles%
%   \automark[chapter]{chapter}
%   \ihead{\headmark}% Inner header
%   \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}% Outer header
    \automark[chapter]{chapter}
    \ohead{Jiangsu University Master's Degree Thesis}
    \ihead{\headmark}% Inner header
}
\ifoot{}% Inner footer
\ofoot{}% Outer footer
\pagestyle{thesisSimple}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\providepairofpagestyles[thesisSimple]{thesis}{%
    \automark*[section]{}
    \ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
}
```

**Note**: Somehow `fancyhdr` is not supported by `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` (line 302). Maybe we need to tweak [scrlayer-scrpage](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf).

Comment: I won't go to some external site to debug your document and a class from a commercial site. You should provide a small complete example *here*.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have provided some relevant code. Please let me know if something more is needed

Comment: Looking over the KOMA docs, they pretty much use standard page styles (with the addition of a few feaures like \chapterpagestyle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to edit the class file. Change the settings in the document preamble:

```latex
\pagestyle{thesis}% defined by the class using package scrlayer-scrpage
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\ttitle}
\rehead{\rightmark}
\lohead{\leftmark}
\rohead{\univname}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% or should there be no page number at all?
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[english,headsepline]{MastersDoctoralThesis}[2017/08/27]% v1.6 LaTeXTemplates.com
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\pagestyle{thesis}% defined by the class using package scrlayer-scrpage
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\ttitle}
\rehead{\rightmark}
\lohead{\leftmark}
\rohead{\univname}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% or should there be no page number at all?

\thesistitle{Thesis Title}
\university{\href{http://www.university.com}{University Name}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{thesis}
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\appendix
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**

If there should be only "Chaptern <chapter number>" and "Section <section number>" in inner header, you can add the following code in the preamble before you select page style `thesis`:

```latex
\providecaptionname{english}{\Sectionname}{Section}
\makeatletter
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{thesis}{onselect={%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptermarkformat}{}}%
  \renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sectionmarkformat}}%
  \renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\@chapapp~\thechapter}%
  \renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{\Sectionname~\thesection}%
}}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[english,headsepline]{MastersDoctoralThesis}[2017/08/27]% v1.6 LaTeXTemplates.com
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\providecaptionname{english}{\Sectionname}{Section}
\makeatletter
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{thesis}{onselect={%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptermarkformat}{}}%
  \renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sectionmarkformat}}%
  \renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\@chapapp~\thechapter}%
  \renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{\Sectionname~\thesection}%
}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{thesis}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\ttitle}
\rehead{\rightmark}
\lohead{\leftmark}
\rohead{\univname}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\thesistitle{Thesis Title}
\university{\href{http://www.university.com}{University Name}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{thesis}
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\appendix
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, there should be page number too, EXACTLY at the position where you specified. :)

Comment: Is there is way, how can we customize `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`? For example, what if we only want to show chapter number, omitting 'chapter' word or only "Chapter 1" omitting chapter name?

Comment: Because some of my chapter titles can be really long. For example:  FSCS-SIMD: An efficient implementation of Fixed-Size-Candidate-Set adaptive random testing using SIMD instructions

Comment: Should all chapters and sections use only "Chapter 1" and "Section 1" in the page header?

Comment: All chapters and sections should use relevant chapters sections. I gave "Chapter 1" as an example for the first chapter.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to create a page style (myheadings).  I used scrbook instead of your thesis, but it should still work.

I added the words *Chapter* and *Section* and used `\arabic{section}` instead of `\thesection`.  It should be noted that `\chaptermark` is called by `\chapter` and is passed the chapter title, while `\sectionmark` is called by `\section` and is passed the section title (which I ignored).  This is so that if more than one section is on a page, the first section is used instead of the last.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@myheadings{% create myheadings pagestyle
    \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
    \def\@evenfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
    \def\@evenhead{\slshape\rightmark\hfil\@title}%
    \def\@oddhead{\slshape Universe City University\hfil\leftmark}%
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo% disable
    \renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{}}%
    \renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{Section \arabic{section}. \ }}% no \sectionname defined
    }
\makeatother

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{myheadings}

\title{My Thesis}
\author{Me}

\usepackage{lipsum}% not part of solution

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\section{Test}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```